# When i run this code it gives me error "Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause'", and is not fetching record from database

Tags: php

```
<?php
$query1 = "select * from users where user_id=" . $_GET['user_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!$res) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
} else {
    echo "succeess";
}
?>
<form method="post" id="editform" action="Updateuser.php"><br/>
    <tr><td><b>User ID</b></td><td>
            <input type="text" name="user_id" style="width:450px;height:30px" value="<? php echo $res['user_id'] ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" style="width:450px;height:30px" value="<?php echo $res['name'] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Role</b></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" style="width:450px;height:30px" value="<?php echo $res['role'] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Password</b></td>
        <td>
            <input type=" text" name="password" style="width:450px;height:30px" value="<?php echo $res['password'] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align=right>
            <input type="submit" name="submit value" id="updatebutton" value="Update Record">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

whenever the code runs it says unknown colomn in where clause, i am sending user_id from the users page to this page. It is displaying user_id in the address bar but it is not fetching the whole record from the database and keeps on displaying that error. Note: My table has that colomn "user_id"

Comment: if it says user_id is unknown column then surely it doesn't exists in the table. You might be making an typo error, double check your database and code

Comment: It's completly open for sql injection. [Sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @VaibhavVishal it do exists i checked it again

Comment: @xmastertje how to prevent it from sql injection?

Comment: see the link above. never use this `$_GET['user_id']` in your query

Comment: @xmastertje thank u so much it worked. Now please tell me how to prevent it from sql injection, you wrote don't use $_GET['user_id'] then what should i write?

Comment: @Anonymus does my answer work?

Comment: @xmastertje no it didn't but the earlier one did, this one is not displaying anything

Comment: @xmastertje can u please help me with this code too, it is not updating the data and i am passing user_id to it.

Comment: <?php
include("conn.php");
$updatequery="Update users SET 
  user_id='".$_POST['user_id']."',
     name='".$_POST['name']."',
  role='".$_POST['role']."',
  password='".$_POST['password']."'
  where user_id='".$_GET['user_id']."'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$updatequery);
if($result){
 header('Location: viewuser.php');  
}
else{
 die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>

Comment: @Anonymus first accept my answer after that i will look to it

Comment: @xmastertje i accept it thanks for that answer now please help me with this one

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: @xmastertje it is not giving any error but it is not updating the data as well

Comment: i think something like this

Comment: `<?php include("conn.php"); 
    $updatequery="Update users SET user_id='".$_POST['user_id']."',
    name='".$_POST['name']."', role='".$_POST['role']."', password='".$_POST['password']."' 
    where user_id='".$_POST['user_id']."'"; 

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $updatequery))
     { header('Location: viewuser.php'); } 
    else{ die(mysqli_error($conn)); } ?> `

Comment: @xmastertje i tried to this before but when i do that it updates the whole record except user_id

Comment: why do you want to update your user id?

Comment: @xmastertje i am making this project for someone and they might have to update it so i have to put this option too

Comment: believe me it's not necessary because you will give it a primary key and make it auto-increment

Comment: it will only give errors

Comment: Actually it contains string values like Sara12, Josh598 and etc so no auto-increment used on this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this:

```
$query1 = "select * from users where user_id=" . $_GET['user_id'];
```

to

```
$query1 = "select * from users where user_id='". $_GET['user_id']."'";
```